# Forbidden 403 Access to this resource on the server is denied

Tags: plugins

I recently installed the WP for my client but, whenever I try to add new plugin, or edit a page with elementor or wordpress editor it says

Forbidden 403 Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I tried all the things like changing permissions, activating/deactivating plugins and changing the .htaccess file, Please help me with this.

[image: d]

Comment: You'll probably need to take this up with your hosting company. Ensure that they've got [the requirements for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) in place.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - the root cause was a "bad" parameter from the LiteSpeed point of view. Correct the field value and it will fix.

More context: if you look closely to the returned page, you can see that in the footer is it written that the page was returned by LiteSpeed - this may mean that it found something that bothered. Please check the request parameters that are sent to backend and identify if there is something strange.
For example, in my case, the issue was when calling /wp-admin/user-edit.php for updating a user password. This not made sense because it failed for only one specific user. I have checked the parameters that were sent and `name` was having its value something like "name-firstName@yahoo.com" - so in a name field was samed an email value. I have changed the user `name` field to be a normal name value and the problem vanished.

For more reading on this: https://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/bbpress-bulk-user-edit-403-error-user-edit-php-403-error/